# Making buildout download packages oauth2, python-openid and django-social-auth

Tags: django, buildout

I've been battling with a problem with the buildout script not downloading certain packages while all the other packages are downloaded correctly.

My buildout script is here:

```
[buildout]
parts = python
        django
        djangoprod
        fabric
        celery

download-cache = downloads
prefer-final = true
install-from-cache = true
#      PIL

# newest=false says "don't check every time to see if there's a newer
# version.  This makes running bin/buildout much faster.
#
# If you want to pull in the latest version of everything, run
# bin/buildout -n
newest=false

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = django
       adodbapi
       ${django:eggs}
extra-paths =
       ${buildout:directory}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
version = 1.2.3
settings = development
eggs = south
       django-celery
       django-celery-email
       django-debug-toolbar
       simplejson
       sorl-thumbnail
       psycopg2
       oauth2
       python-openid
       django-social-auth
project = project

[djangoprod]
# We have 2 rules for django here because we want the WSGI script to use
# production settings and bin/django (commandline) to use development
# settings.
recipe = djangorecipe
version = ${django:version}
wsgi = true
wsgilog = /var/www/roonga/logs/wsgi.log
settings = production
eggs = ${django:eggs}
project = ${django:project}
extra-paths =
       ${django:extra-paths}

[south]
# http://south.aeracode.org/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[fabric]
# http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.2/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[celery]
# http://celeryproject.org/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg

[celerymon]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celerymon/0.2.0
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[django-celery]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[django-celery-email]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[django-debug-toolbar]
# http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[simplejson]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[sorl-thumbnail]
# http://thumbnail.sorl.net/docs/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[psycopg2]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[oauth2]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[python-openid]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-openid/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest

[django-social-auth]
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth/
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
version = newest
```

The packages that is fails to download are oauth2, python-openid and django-social-auth. The error message is always:

```
Couldn't find index page for <package_name> (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for <package_name>.
While:
  Installing django.
  Getting distribution for <package_name>.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for <package_name>.
```

I have tried each package separately but it always fails. I have also tried putting the links in directly and specifying the part in parts but still have not got any results.

Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide.

nav

Comment: Do I need to provide any more information please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
install-from-cache = true
```

Which means that if those packages are not in your cache, your buildout will fail. Unset that option and it should work as expected.